# SQL - GROUP BY having count, joining multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, having

I have 4 tables:

```
Entries:
id
year
day

AnalysisText:
id
text
entries_id

AnalysisType:
id
type

AnalysisTextTypes:
id
analysistext_id
analysistype_id
```

Example data:

```
entries     
id  year    day
1   2010    1
2   2011    4
3   2012    6


AnalysisText        
id  text    entries_id
1   blah    2
2   more blah   1
3   blah blah   1

AnalysisType        
id  type    
1   A   
2   B   
3   C   

AnalysisTextTypes       
id  analysistext_id analysistype_id
1   1   1
2   1   2
3   2   3
4   3   1
```

I need to get all the `analysistext` values that have more than one `analysistype`, and also all the `entries` associated with these `analysistext` that have more than one `analysistype`.

So in the data above, we want result

```
my_date text    type
2011-4  blah    A
2011-4  blah    B
```

Because that is the text that has more than one type.

The query below works, but it feels inefficient to use a subquery to identify `analysisText` values with more than `analysisType`:

```
select  
CONCAT(e.year, '-', e.day) as my_date,
x.text,
y.type
from entries e
join analysistext x on e.id = x.entries_id
join analysistext_types xy on xy.analysistext_id = x.id
join analysistype y on y.id = xy.analysistype_id
where xy.analysistext_id in (
    select analysistext_id
    from analysistext_types
    group by analysistext_id
    having count(analysistype_id) > 1
) order by my_date, analysis_text, type;
```

I want one query where we `SELECT` the fields of interest from the joined tables, and do the `group by` and `having count` directly on the tables being joined. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You may use a self-join to avoid subquery completely

```
select concat(e.year, '-' ,e.day), at.text ,ant.type
from AnalysisText at
join entries e on at.entries_id = e.id
join AnalysisTextTypes att on att.analysistext_id = at.id
join AnalysisType ant on att.analysistype_id = ant.id
join AnalysisTextTypes att2 on att2.analysistext_id = att.analysistext_id
group by att2.analysistext_id
having count(att2.analysistext_id) > 1
```

Comment: I don't see the difference between this and my query? This includes the nested subquery in the `WHERE` clause that I'm trying to avoid. I want the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` to happen on the joined tables, rather than within the `WHERE` clause. My sense is this would not only be more elegant but more efficient.